# Is possible to access ATTR for Perl packages without defining a getter?

Tags: perl

I am currently working on a Perl 5.8 project.
I have package that looks like:

```
package Foo::Bar;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Class::Std;

our @EXPORT_SAFE = qw(Class::Std);

my %baz :ATTR;

sub BUILD {
  my ($self, $ident, $args) = @_;
  
  $baz{$ident} = $$args{something};
}
```

I am not exposing `baz` with any getter, but I would like to fetch it's content for unit testing purposes. There is any way to do it in Perl?

e.g. in Ruby you can `some_instance.instance_variable_get("@#{name}")`

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Perl 5.8. From 2002! Why do people do this to themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The answer in the general case is "it depends (but probably)".

The answer in your case is "no".

**Detail**

There is no fixed way to implement classes and objects in Perl. In *most* cases an object will be a blessed reference to a hash. In those cases, you could simply treat the object reference as a hash reference and look up the key directly. So, code like this:

```
my $baz = $obj->{baz};
```

However, you're not using the most common approach to building Perl objects, you're using [Class::Std](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Std). And Class::Std does things rather differently. Class::Std uses an approach called "inside-out objects" which was popularised by Damian Conway in *Object Oriented Perl* and which was very fashionable for a while about twenty years ago.

In normal objects, you have a hash for each object. The keys are the attribute names and the values are the attribute values. With inside-out objects, each attribute has its own hash. The keys are the stringified references to an individual object and the value is the attribute's value for that object.

In effect, the "standard" approach is:

```
$object{attr} = value;
```

And the inside out approach is:

```
$attr{object} = value;
```

One of the big reasons why people liked inside-out objects is that the attribute hashes can be lexical variables stored in the class's source code. And that means they are truly private and cannot be accessed from outside of the class - except by using the provided accessor methods. Which is great if you want to force Perl to implement a far stronger kind of encapsulation. But terrible if you want to break through that encapsulation in the way that you do here.

So, no. In your case, you can't do this.

Comment: Actually I tried dump the content of my instance and I got something like `bless( do{\(my $o = undef)}, 'Foo::Bar')` and when I try to to access the `$obj->{baz}` I get a not an HASH reference error. Thank you for the explanation then!

Comment: @mabe02: Yeah, inside-out objects contain no data. That's confused me a few times in the past :-)

Comment: And therein lies one the problem with them: They make debugging harder. (Yes, it's not necessarily a major problem. After all, an XS-based object might be similar in appearance.)

Answer (score 2):

Class::Std could easily provide `->instance_variable_get`, at least for variables that were given a name.<sup>[1]</sup> But it doesn't.

---

In the absence of something provided by Class::Std, you could add the following to your class:

```perl
use Carp qw( croak );

sub instance_variable_get {
   my ($self, $name) = @_;

   my $pkg_glob = do {
      no strict qw( refs );
      *{ __PACKAGE__ . "::" }
   };

   exists($pkg_glob->{$name})
      or croak("Unknown attribute $name");

   my $hash = *{ $pkg_glob->{$name} }{HASH}
      or croak("Unknown attribute $name");

   return $hash->{ident($self)};
}
```

*Note that this requires using `our` instead of `my` for the hashes.*

This will allow you to use

```perl
$some_instance->instance_variable_get('baz')
```

Of course, if you're using `our` for the hashes, you could also use

```perl
$Foo::Bar::baz{ $some_instance->ident }
```

---

1. Currently, `:ATTR( :name<...> )`, `:ATTR( :init_arg<...> )`, `:ATTR( :get<...> )` and `:ATTR( :set<...> )` provide a name for the attribute, though these all have other effects as well.

Comment: it looks very promising. I am going to check it tomorrow morning.